# Rails decimal migration produces integer columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, decimal

I'm running Rails 3.1.1 using the mysql2 gem (v0.3.11). For some reason, when adding some decimal columns to a table, it produces integer fields. It does not give me any error, and the migration shows that decimal columns are being created. Has anyone else run into this problem? Here's a line from my migration:

`add_column :tracks, :energy, :decimal, precision: 18`

I don't usually run to StackOverflow but I really don't know where to look for the problem.

Comment: Can you post "tracks" block from `schema.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

try adding `:scale => x` (where `x` is the number digits you need to the right of the decimal point) to the line in your migration.

[source and more information](http://torontoprogrammer.ca/2010/05/decimal-numbers-in-rails-and-mysql/)